# Почему при submit из Marionette.ItemView срабатывает submit Form в родительском Marionette.LayoutView?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette.js

Доброе время суток. Проблема из-за которой приходится на выходных сидеть на работе.  Создаю представление Marionette.LayoutView в шаблоне которого есть форма с сабмитом.

```
var FormModel = require("А"),
    ConfirmCodeView = require("..."),
    Template = require("А"),

require("user/behaviors/behaviors");

var globalChannel = Backbone.Wreqr.radio.channel("global"),
    ...
    FormView;

FormView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    className: "confirm-personal-data-view",
    getTemplate: function () {
       return Template;
    },

    behaviors: {
        KeyboardScroll: {
            scrollEl: "form .content"
        },
        RequiredField: {},
        ProfileName: {},
        ProfileValidation: {}
    },

    ui: {
        form: "form"
    },

    initialize: function (options) {
        this.model = new FormModel({...});
    },

    onRoute: function (step, confirmMethod, requestId) {
        if (confirmMethod && requestId) {

            this.addRegions({
                phoneConfirm: "#region-phone-confirm"
            });

            this.getRegion("phoneConfirm").show(new ConfirmCodeView({
                ...
            }));
        }
    },

    modelEvents:  {
        ...
    },

    events: {
        ...
    },



    submitForm: function () {
        console.log("dataSubmit");
        ...
    }

});

return FormView;
```

Через регион отображаю дочернее представление ConfirmCodeView  - Marionette.ItemView. В темплейте которого также есть форма с сабмитом

```
var i18n = require("i18n"),
    templateHelpers = require("app/template-helpers"),
    FormModel = require("Б"),
    template = require("Б");
require("user/behaviors/behaviors");

var modalChannel = Backbone.Wreqr.radio.channel("modal"),
    FormView;

FormView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    className: "confirm-personal-phone-view",
    template: template,

    behaviors: {
        KeyboardScroll: {
            scrollEl: "form .content"
        },
        RequiredField: {},
        ProfileValidation: {}
    },

    ui: {
        form: "form[name=verify-code]"
    },

    initialize: function (options) {

        this.model = new FormModel({
            ...
        });
    },

    events: {
        ...
    },


    submitForm: function () {
        console.log("codeSubmit");
    }
});

return FormView;
```

Проблема заключается в том, что нажатие `Input[type=submit]` или `this.ui.form.submit()`  из дочернего ConfirmCodeView  - Marionette.ItemView ведет к срабатыванию submitForm **ТОЛЬКО** в родительском LayoutView.

Вариант напрямую вызова функции `this.submitForm()` при клике по кнопке не подходит, так как в bihaviors происходит отлавливание события **SUBMIT** из View и срабатывает проверка, фокус и скрол пустых полей, и если все норм выполнится `submitForm()`.

Может кто подскажет с чем это может быть связано? Обработку событий и код behaviors не стал выкладывать, так как думаю, что проблема в нехватке каких-то теоретических знаний.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сколько я знаю, вложенные формы нормально не работают. Возможно в этом причина.

И второй вариант, заблокируйте всплытие события в дочерней форме.

```js
submitForm: function(e) {
    if (e && e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, я совсем забыл про e.preventDefault